# How is macro replacement performed in complex situations?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Consider the following sample code.

```
#define T(q) L##q
#define A(p) T("x" T(#p))
wchar_t w[] = A(a);
```

Is this code well-formed? What is the value of `w`? Is the behavior different in **C** and C++? Is it different in C++0x?

I've browsed through the C++03 standard and it seems to me, that the code should be valid with `w` having the value `L"xa"`.

1. Invocation of `A` is found, processing thereof yields the pp sequence `T ( "x" T ( "a" ) )`.
2. Invocation of `T` is found, yielding `L ## "x" T ( "a" )`, which in turn yields `L"x" T ( "a" )`.
3. Invocation of `T` is found, yielding `L"x" L"a"`.

Is that correct? Neither EDG nor Clang accept the snippet, MSVC 9 compiles it just fine.

Comment: I would have thought it expands to `L"x" T("a")` too. In the result token sequence of a macro, the name of the macro is never considered for substitution again. So the `T("a")` is not again substituted - step `3` is not done.

Comment: this article explains the macro expansion algorithm http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Macro-Expansion.html

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't consider the fact that the macro is being expanded twice...

Comment: @litb, perhaps you'd like to copy-paste the comment into an answer? I'm offering 25 rep for that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

g++ expands to

```
L"x" T("a")
```

Macro cannot be recursive and they are pre-processed only in one shot, so `T(#p)` would not be expanded again. If you wanted `L"xa"` then following can be done:

```
#define A(p) T("x")#p
#define T(q) L##q
```

(It's actually `L"x""a"`.)

Comment: Note that MSVC won't accept `L"x" "a"` as a valid string literal.  So the OP will still be left in a position of having an `A()` macro that works on one compiler, but not another.  `#define A(p) T("x") T(#p)` will expand to `L"x" L"a"` and will work on both compilers.